# TIdHTTP raise Exception "Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer"

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

When I get a URL with TIdHTTP, it displays an error dialog:

> Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer

I don't want to display this error dialog. How can I catch the error with `try...catch` and don't show it?

Comment: `try..catch` is for C++, Delphi uses `try..except` instead: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Exceptions_(Delphi) That being said, what is the actual problem you are having with catching the exception? Indy's exceptions work like any other library's exceptions, there is nothing magic about them. Catching exceptions is a fundamental skill any Delphi dev should know. So please show the actual code you are having trouble with.

Comment: tks.  Replace sslvTLSv3 with sslvTLSv1，Replace   pv1_0 with pv1_1  is OK .

Comment: there is no `sslvTLSv3`, I assume you meant `sslvSSLv3` instead.